# Relationship between projection and vector as sum of parallel and perpendicular parts

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, projection

I'm reading a Linear Algebra text that looks to me like it has a contradiction. The exact text is linked below, but here is a summary:

Given two vectors, v and n, you can define v as the sum of a vector perpendicular to n and a vector parallel to v. The *parallel vector* is referred to as the *projection* of v onto n.

Which leads to this equation:

$$v_{||} = n\frac{\left|\left|v_{||}\right|\right|}{\left|\left|n\right|\right|}$$

The idea being that since the vectors are parallel they only differ in magnitude. But can't they also point in exactly opposite directions?

If you take the v vector in the picture, and mirror it around the y axis so it now points up and to the left, then the parallel part of the sum now points in the direction opposite n. However as I understand it projection is defined such that it always points in the direction of the vector being projected onto. So shouldn't the equation be:

$$v_{||} = n\frac{\left|\left|v_{||}\right|\right|}{\left|\left|n\right|\right|}$$ when the angle between v and n is less than 90 degrees

and

$$v_{||} = -n\frac{\left|\left|v_{||}\right|\right|}{\left|\left|n\right|\right|}$$ when the angle between v and n is greater than 90 degrees

?

[image]

Comment: In the image you’ve included, it looks to me like the equation refers specifically to the situation in the diagram, in which the angle is acute. It’s not a general formula for $\mathbf v_\parallel$.

Comment: @amd possibly that's the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 
$$
v = v_\perp + v_\parallel
$$
with
$$
n \cdot v_\perp = 0 \\
v_\parallel = s \, n
$$
where $s$ is a scalar and $n \ne 0$. We want to treat the case $v_\parallel \ne 0$, so $s \ne 0$. Then
$$
v_\parallel \cdot n 
= (s \, n) \cdot n
= s (n \cdot n)
= s \, \lVert n \rVert^2
$$
on the other hand
$$
v_\parallel \cdot n 
= \lVert v_\parallel \rVert \lVert n \rVert \cos\angle(v_\parallel, n)
= \lvert s \rvert \lVert n \rVert^2 \cos\angle(v_\parallel, n)
$$
where we used
$$
\lVert v_\parallel \rVert 
= \lVert s \, n \rVert
= \lvert s \lvert \lVert n \rVert
$$
so for $\lVert n \rVert \ne 0$ we have
$$
s  = \lvert s \rvert \cos\angle(v_\parallel, n)
$$
or
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{cos}{cos}
\cos\angle(v_\parallel, n) = \frac{s}{\lvert s \rvert} = \sgn(s)
$$
which is the sign of the scalar $s$.

We have
$$
v_\parallel 
= s \, n 
= s \, \lVert n \rVert \frac{n}{\lVert n \rVert}
= (\sgn(s) \lvert s \rvert) \, \lVert n \rVert \frac{n}{\lVert n \rVert}
$$
On the other hand we saw
$$
\lVert v_\parallel \rVert 
= \lvert s \lvert \lVert n \rVert
$$
so we have
$$
v_\parallel 
= \sgn(s) \lVert v_\parallel \rVert \frac{n}{\lVert n \rVert}
= \sgn(s) n \frac{\lVert v_\parallel \rVert}{\lVert n \rVert}
$$
which answers your question with a yes.

Comment: Strictly speaking I think you also need to constrain s to not equal 0 (both for the definition of the parallel vector and to prevent how you're defining sgn from breaking). But I get what you mean